# How do I launch an application via a web intent without prompting for the browser?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm working on an in-phone search engine, and I want to be able to launch applications when someone clicks on a search result. Some apps have custom uri schemes I can use to launch the app - for example:

untappd://beers/123

However - there are some apps that don't have (or don't publish) custom uri schemes. Happily, many of these apps have web intents, so for example if you launch an intent with this url:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wellington

It will prompt to open the URL in the Wikipedia app, or in chrome. Is it possible to get android to launch into the Wikipedia app directly, without prompting for whether the user wants to open it in chrome or the wikipedia app?

Answer (score 1):

No. If multiple apps can handle the same http uri scheme the user will be given the choice which to use. They can of course then choose to "always use this option" when they choose the app to use.

Comment: It's not possible to launch an app directly and pass the uri as an extra to the intent?

Comment: Of course but that is not the same thing as your original question. Any such data can be sent with an intent. I was assuming you were using the system to launch the uri (you said launch with a web intent) and not starting an app with a specific extra.

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear - but yeah, looks like I want to use setClassName and setData and that'll launch the app directly.